# Using Convert on an ELSE CASE SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, case-when, sql-convert

I am performing a SQL query in Postgres, which selects a numeric field. I need to display a string value as the result of this SELECT, so I am using a `CASE` statement like this:

```
Select 
case numeric_field
when 100 then 'some string'
when 200 then 'some other string'
```

The problem is that if the numeric field has any other value (like `300` for example), I need to display this value (as a string of course). I try to put a `CONVERT` on the else like this

```
...
else CONVERT(varchar(10),numeric_field)
```

But it didn't work. How do I do this?

Comment: `CONVERT` is, so far as I'm aware, only in the T-SQL dialect of SQL (found in MS SQL Server and Sybase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE numeric_field
          WHEN 100 THEN 'some string'
          WHEN 200 THEN 'some other string'
          ELSE numeric_field::text
       END AS result
```

- Your statement was incomplete, `END` was missing. [Read the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)
- To output a numeric field as text, just cast it to text: `numeric_field::text`, which is the Postgres specific short form of the SQL standard call:

  ```
  cast (numeric_field AS text)
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didnt put the end for saving space :P, but your solution works really well, thanks again.